# Laravel (Eloquent): how to get relationship used to access model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to do this within my controller:

```
$id = $post->user->id;
```

Then within my model be able to do this somehow:

```
$calling = $this->callingModel; //should be Post model
```

How can I access the calling class like this from within a model?

Background: For better or worse, I am attempting to limit access to model attributes within accessors for my models. Generally this is based on user permissions, but in one specific case I'm actually limiting access based on the relationship used to access the model.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited to try to make clearer.

Comment: Have you checked the [polymorphic relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations)?

Comment: not quite, that's defining a basically normal eloquent relationship that can be one thing or another and accessing whichever "that" is. What I need instead is to know the context in which my model is being called.

Comment: You can't do it (except to m-m relations in some way), and I wouldn't ever do that anyway. This is not a good approach. Instead create another service that will handle the permissions, including this very case. Model should not be aware of the context it is called in the way you try. **However** you probably can achieve what you need by polymorphism (extending related class, not relation). Show sample of what you need to do.